# iOS 9 Picture in Picture issue for playing live streaming video

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller

I got a very strange issue when I play the live stream video in Picture in Picture mode. Please refer to my screenshot:

[image]

When I press the "Pause" button for a while and press "Play" button, the video won't start.

This is working fine for VOD. I'm wondering what's wrong with it.

Here is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let dest = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayerViewController
    dest.delegate = self
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://mylivestreamurl/playlist.m3u8")
    if let movieUrl = url {
        dest.player = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
        dest.player?.play()
    }
}

func playerViewController(playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {

    let currentViewController = navigationController?.visibleViewController
    if currentViewController != playerViewController {
        if let topViewController = navigationController?.topViewController {
            topViewController.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                completionHandler(true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: If it's possible to hide the play/pause button in PiP?

Comment: Upvote from me. I also have the same issue. I initially experienced it in a player that had custom UI and so I thought perhaps there was an issue with using my own `AVPlayerLayer`, but creating a new skeletal app with only an AVPlayerViewController yields the same result. Streaming form a Wowza server. On-demand videos work for me as well. Only an issue with live streams.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the video segments required to resume playback are no longer available on the content server, or did you check that? If AVPlayer buffered the live content in the background while paused then resume would be possible (limited by the local buffer size), but I don't think this is happening. Would be nice if it was possible to hide the pause button when live streaming. I haven't found a way to do that, at least not yet.

Comment: I've now tested with my app. It appears the PiP controller pause/play works for me with a live stream. If I pause for a while the player jumps forward to current time on play.

Comment: The play/pause is working fine inside my application through AVPlayer. But it doesn't work through PiP.